# ExtJS 4 - Styling a window.MessageBox

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application and I have a pop up window as such:

```
var myMsgBox = new Ext.window.MessageBox({
    cls: 'msgbox',
    bodyCls: 'popWindow'
});
myMsgBox.textField.inputType = 'password';
myMsgBox.textField.width = 240;
myMsgBox.textField.center();
myMsgBox.prompt(title, msg, myCallback);
```

And I am trying to style it. However, it seems that only the `background` and `text-align` properties are working, setting the `font-style`, `font-family`, and `font-weight` do not. Here are my css files:

msgbox.css

```
.msgbox {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important;
}
```

popwindow.css

```
.popWindow .x-container .x-box-item {
    text-align: center ;
    font-size: 17px ;
    font-weight: bold ;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' ;
}

.popWindow .x-form-item-body {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important;
}
```

How do I style the title and message of the message box?

Update 1, I got the font family and font size to work by doing:

```
.popWindow .x-form-display-field{
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important;
}
```

however, the alignment is still not working

Comment: The text is in two div containers - one for the header, one for the body. You should inspect elements to find the classes these div containers have, for they are using for text styles in the theme, not the parent element. I would guess they are called sth like `.msgbox .x-messagebox-header` and `.msgbox .x-messagebox-body` or sth like this, but please inspect the messagebox element in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what made it work.

`.msgbox` - aligns the title

`.x-header-text` -  takes care of the title styles except the alignment

`.x-form-display-field` and `.x-form-item-body .x-form-display-field-body` - takes care of the message/body property. I forgot which one takes care of the alignment and which one takes care of the styles (if they are separate in the first place).

```
.msgbox{
    text-align: center !important;
}

.msgbox .x-header-text {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: 'Arial' !important;
    color: red;
}

.msgbox .x-form-display-field{
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    font-family: 'Arial' !important;
}

.msgbox .x-form-item-body .x-form-display-field-body {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    font-family: 'Arial' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the title like this:

```
title: '<div id="title" align="center">TEXT</div>',
```

In css:

```
#title {
  color: @Blue
}
```